# Generating a list of random numbers with foldM

Tags: haskell, random, monads

I want to generate a list of random numbers, where the range of each random number is determined by elements of a provided list. I thought I had something that made sense, but I get errors I don't understand :(

Here's what I have:

```
useRNG nums min = do
    generator <- get
    let (val, generator') = randomR (min, 51) generator
    put generator'
    return $ val : nums

foldM useRNG [] [0 .. 50]
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `useRNG` can generate all kinds of numbers (any instance of `Random`), and work in all kinds of monads (any state monad whose state is an instance of `RandomGen`), as can be seen from its inferred type signature:

```
GHCi> :t useRNG
useRNG
  :: (MonadState s m, RandomGen s, Random a, Num a) =>
     [a] -> a -> m [a]
```

...but when you use it, you haven't specified *which* concrete types you actually want.

If you disambiguate with a type signature:

```
test :: State StdGen [Int]
test = foldM useRNG [] [0 .. 50]
```

then it works fine. You could also accomplish this by putting a type signature on `useRNG`:

```
useRNG :: [Int] -> Int -> State StdGen [Int]
```

Now, you might be thinking: if `useRNG` works fine with all these types, why can't `test` too? The answer is the [*monomorphism restriction*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), which is fairly arcane and not well-liked by many Haskell users. You can avoid it by either putting

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

at the top of your file, or giving `test` an explicit type signature:

```
test :: (RandomGen g, Random a, Num a, Enum a, MonadState g m) => m [a]
```

You can find out the correct type signature with GHCi:

```
GHCi> :t foldM useRNG [] [0 .. 50]
foldM useRNG [] [0 .. 50]
  :: (MonadState s m, RandomGen s, Random b, Num b, Enum b) => m [b]
```

(I wrote the explicit type signature before checking with GHCi, which is why mine is slightly different.)

However, this type signature is a little *too* polymorphic for practical uses — you'll basically be putting the ambiguity off until you actually use the result — so I'd suggest specifying it more concretely in this instance. You could, for instance, keep `test` generic over the type of random number without the needless polymorphism over the state monad and generator type:

```
test :: (Random a, Num a, Enum a) => State StdGen [a]
```

You might also want to consider using [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom), which wraps all the standard random number generation facilities in a state monad-based interface so you don't have to :)